# Ajax ignores request method

Tags: ajax

I've a JS running trying to create a POST request using $.ajax
However, it keeps failing because the browser/code ignores the custom header/method i use.

Here's my code:

```
function test() {

    $.ajaxSetup({

            type: "POST"

    });


var url = 'url';

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: "Basic=YWRtaW46cHNhZG0xbg==",
    headers: {
        Basic: 'YWRtaW46cHNhZG0xbg=='
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

}

And here's the result on the browser:

```
Response Headersview source
Allow   POST,DELETE,OPTIONS
Content-Length  1034
Content-Type    text/html;charset=utf-8
Date    Fri, 15 Nov 2013 09:30:47 GMT
Server  NA
Request Headersview source
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  JSESSIONID=6C2CD009C18C54F050AE6C2C66749544
Host    172.16.0.2:8083
Referer http://172.16.0.3/ss/v1/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
```

I'm being rejected because the browser is using GET instead of POST (it also doesn't send the custom header but i guess that the same issue).